# What means /V key when Windows Installer service starts?

Tags: windows, service, key, windows-installer

Windows Installer service starts as

```
C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe /V
```

I read standard help to msiexec but not found this key description.

What it means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Rob van der Woude](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/msiexec.php), it is a "repair option" which recaches the local package.  A few others say the same.

However, this Microsoft page says it is merely a "verbose" switch: *[Basic troubleshooting steps for Windows Installer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/907749)*  (article 907749).

Comment: thanks, maybe I don't understand, but it says /f[p|e|c|m|s|o|d|a|u|v] <Product.msi | ProductCode> that means /f key and after optional p or e or ... v option and after name of msi package or product code, but there is no /v option without /f key

Comment: thanks for article 907749 - it's useful, though a bit strange to see /V key description there and not in the main help

Comment: Perhaps it was overlooked because it is less important (or because it is a common option).

Comment: @ThomasDickey In fine, is `/V` a "repair option" of `msiexec` or a "verbose" switch ?